# How to send the Expression Parameter to Web Api

Tags: c#, linq, api, get, expression

I have a Web Api project. 
This method calling the web api.

```
    public User GetUser(Expression<Func<User, bool>> where)
    {
        HttpClient Client = new HttpClient();

        Client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://192.168.2.139:23283/api/user/");

        var responseTask = Client.GetAsync("GetUserByExpression?id=" + where);
        responseTask.Wait();

        var result = responseTask.Result;
        if (result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            var readTask = result.Content.ReadAsAsync<User>();
            readTask.Wait();

            return readTask.Result;
        }
        else
        {
            return new User();
        }
    }
```

var test=GetUser(p=>p.Id==1);
After using the method, it enters the api but the parameter is null.

```
 [HttpGet]
    [Route("GetUserByExpression")]
    public HttpResponseMessage GetUserByExpression(Expression<Func<User, bool>> where)
    {
        try
        {
            var user = repoUser.Find(where);
            if (user != null)
            {
                return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, user);
            }
            else
            {
                return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, "User not found.");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception exp)
        {
            return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, exp.Message);
        }
    }
```

The "where" parameter is null when I call the Get method. Therefore, I can not make a healthy operation. What can I do to prevent this parameter from going to null?

Comment: In your `Get` method of API, call you parameters like this: `GetUserByExpression([FromQuery] Expression<Func<User, bool>> id)`. Also you can route your Get method like this: `[HttpGet("GetUserByExpression")]`

Comment: This is true for .net core but i asked for web api.

Comment: You can use `FromRouteAttribute` in your case since its a GET request. The `FromRoute` will look at your route parameters and extract / bind the data based on that. As the route, when called externally, is usually based on the URL. In previous version(s) of web api this is comparable to `FromUri`. You can do something like: `GetUserByExpression([FromRoute] Expression<Func<User, bool>> id)`